# How to play video using Servlet or JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, video-streaming

How to play video using Servlet or JSP?

Comment: you have to stream it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JSP, it's not different from as you would do in normal HTML. Just use the `<embed>` and/or the `<object>` element which points to an URL where the video file is located. You need to consult the documentation of the video format vendor for details how to use it. Since you didn't mention what format the video file is in, we can't help you further in detail. So here's just one example: in case of Quicktime `.mov` files, you can consult it at [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html).

A servlet is only useful if you haven't stored the video file in public webcontent. But still then, it's nothing special which needs to be done by the servlet. Just read `InputStream` from the file source (somewhere else on fixed disk, or in a database, etc) and write to `OutputStream` of the response along a correct set of response headers.

Comment: BUT THERE IS PROBLEM WITH MORZILA FIRE FOX

Comment: That problem would be totally unrelated to JSP since that runs at webserver, not webbrowser. Turn off the caps lock, press `Ask Question` button on right top, post the HTML code you have as far and describe to in depth detail the problems you have in Firefox which don't occur in other browsers (name them as well).